# Find overlapping date ranges and end date the overlapped records

Tags: sql-server, date

I am looking to find the overlappable records and end date them appropriately like lhe results below in SQL Server. If possible I also like to have all the merged id's in the result.

```
declare @t table(id int identity(1,1), name varchar(20), startdatetime datetime, enddatetime datetime);

insert into @t(name, startdatetime, enddatetime)
values
('ABC', '20200102 08:30', '20200102 09:30'),
('ABC', '20200102 08:31', '20200102 10:30'),
('ABC', '20200102 04:40', '20200102 05:30'),
('ABC', '20200102 04:55', '20200102 07:30'),
('XYZ', '20200102 04:40', '20200102 05:30'),
('XYZ', '20200102 04:40', '20200102 05:30'),
('XYZ', '20200102 05:20', '20200102 06:30'),
--
('x', '20200102 02:40', '20200102 03:30'),
('x', '20200102 03:30', '20200102 04:55'),
('x', '20200102 04:20', '20200102 05:35'),
('x', '20200102 05:35', '20200102 06:42'),
('x', '20200102 06:00', '20200102 08:15');
```

Expected results like this

```
id  name    startdatetime   enddatetime
1   ABC     20200102 08:30  20200102 08:30
2   ABC     20200102 08:31  20200102 10:30
3   ABC     20200102 04:40  20200102 04:54
4   ABC     20200102 04:55  20200102 07:30
```

I tried few queries and they all overlap but doesn't give the results I need.

Comment: can you explain how the expected result comes about? Also what does `end date them appropriately` means exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that end date them appropriately means subtracting 1 minute from the overlapping startdatetime, and that no record can be completely within another this is probably a good start for your code.

```
SELECT t.id,
   t.name,
   t.startdatetime,
   CASE
       WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN t.enddatetime
       ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, t2.startdatetime)
   END AS adjustedEndDateTime
FROM @t AS t
     LEFT JOIN @t AS t2 ON t.name = t2.name 
     AND t.startdatetime < t2.startdatetime 
     AND t.enddatetime > t2.startdatetime
```

If your records can fully overlap then you'll need to add some extra conditions around t2.enddatetime.

This is the results it gives for name = 'ABC'

```
id  name    startdatetime              adjustedEndDateTime
1   ABC     2020-01-02 08:30:00.000    2020-01-02 08:30:00.000
2   ABC     2020-01-02 08:31:00.000    2020-01-02 10:30:00.000
3   ABC     2020-01-02 04:40:00.000    2020-01-02 04:54:00.000
4   ABC     2020-01-02 04:55:00.000    2020-01-02 07:30:00.000
```